# print the number of words of a string, with the split function

Tags: python

```
def number_of_words_in(text):
    return text

text = "She stopped. Turned around. Oops, a bear. Just like that."
x = char(text)
print(text.split())
```

Hello everyone,

I have to implement a code with output 10, because the amount of words in the text are 10. How can I edit this code, so I get an output of 10. I cant use a loop. And can someone explain to me the split function. Did I do this right?

Comment: char = len by the way

Comment: What part of the `split()` method's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) don't you understand?

Answer (score -1):

```
def number_of_words_in(text):
    return len(text.split(" "))

text = "She stopped. Turned around. Oops, a bear. Just like that."
x = number_of_words_in(text)
print(x)
```

The `split`-function splits the given string into a list. It takes the separator as parameter. For example, above the separator is single whitespace (which is also the default value without any parameter).

Answer (score -1):

```
def number_of_words_in(text):
  return len(text)##returns length of the array.

text="She stopped. Turned around. Oops, a bear. Just like that."
text=text.split()#Converts string into an array of words. ['She', 'stopped.', etc., etc]
print(number_of_words_in(text))
```

You can do it like this without using loop.